# Access files outside a chroot'ed environment?

Tags: centos, chroot

I need to setup some users to access our server. I thought the most secure way to allow them access was to setup a chroot'ed jail for them to log into.

But I need them to access a few select directories that are outside the chroot'ed environment. Apparently I can't use symlinks for this. What is the best approach? Can a chroot'ed environment not be used for this purpose?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a chroot'ed environment to prevent access to files outside of the chroot? So, any way around that would be a bug?

Comment: Maybe you could suggest a better way for me to set this up then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a place where a [bind mount](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/mount_bind.html) will do what you want.

Comment: A bind mount would likely be the best way out of this hole.  

"mount -o bind /dir/outside/chroot /dir/inside/chroot" To survive a reboot add "/dir/inside/chroot /dir/outside/chroot none bind 0 0" to your /etc/fstab file.

Answer (score 2):

If it's on the same filesystem and it's individual files, hardlinks will work.

Softlinks will not work: the main purpose of a chroot'ed jail is that users can't get out to access files that aren't inside there.

You can use `cp -lr` to duplicate a directory tree with each file being a hardlink to the same underlying file, but that won't immediately pick up renames/moves, new files or deletes.

I think [@SvenW](https://serverfault.com/users/8897/svenw) has the best idea: move the directory into the chroot area and make the current location a symlink to the version inside the chroot.

Comment: I get "Invalid cross-device link". The files are on a different internal hdd. Guess that's not gonna work.

Comment: Maybe you could move the files into the required file system and then maybe use symlinks for other non-chrooted users?